# What is the possibility to get a B2 visa if I have an Italian Carta di Soggiorno (Permanent residence card)?

Tags: usa, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a citizen of Bangladesh and have an Italian Carta di Soggiorno (Permanent residence card). Now I want to travel USA for tourism. What is the possibility of getting a B2 visa if I apply now?

Comment: Impossible to say -- your application will be judged based on your particular circumstances, and it would be pretty impossible to assign pribabilities to that even if you did tell us everything about your circumstances.

Comment: Thank for the reply..Here I am living Italy for 5 years ..Did finished MSc in electronics Engineering from Politecnico DI Torino .I am doing A job now and have my House(Rental). I have sufficient money if they ask for in my Bank to stay at USA for 1 week . Please let me know if u need anything else

Comment: @mdmamunurrashid Any partner or family in Italy?

Comment: Yes I have My uncle who is a citizen of Italy

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As noted, no one here has access to statistics about how may people of such-and-such circumstances get approved for such-and-such type of visa or not, for any country. Consular officials are trying to make sure a visa applicant is not attempting to immigrate (because they have strong ties elsewhere like a job or young children) and is not going to be a burden on citizens by taking work, committing crimes, collecting welfare, etc. but there is no checklist of things that will guarantee a visa will be granted.